# Compare i+1 to i in a list, remove by condition, continue comparing only with remaining elements

Tags: python, list, loops, conditional-statements, compare

I have a df with the headers "date" and "dif_to_forelast" and a function with a for-loop that identifies clusters where dif_to_forelast is <= -0.1. It extracts the first date of each cluster and stores them in a list called first_date. This list is then used to create a dictionary inside each loop, and in the end all dictionaries are merged to output a CSV file.

The list may have from 0 to 4 elements. Here are some examples:

```
1: []           
2: [06/07/2017]         
3: [23/05/2017, 24/06/2017] 
4: [19/05/2018, 03/06/2018, 16/06/2018]
5: [18/05/2019, 23/06/2019, 01/07/2019, 06/07/2019]
```

Each date needs to be spaced out by more than 20 days. If two dates are less than 20 days from one another, only the date with the lowest "dif_to_forelast" is to be chosen. For the examples above, this choice would need to be made for some elements of lists 4 and 5.

I want to make this choice starting with the first pair of dates (first_date[0] and first_date[1]) before following to the second (first_date[1] and first_date[2], if available).

The problem with lists of 3 or 4 elements is that the decision for elements 0 and 1 influence which date will be taken to compare with element 2, and this decision influences the next decision process in lists of 4 elements.

For example, in list 4, if 19/05/2018 is the valid date after the first process, the function should continue comparing that date (which is still element 0 in the list) with 16/06/2018 (the next element, 2). The final output should be [19/05/2018, 16/06/2018].

I haven't been able to figure out a code that elegantly considers all list sizes, applies the choosing procedure, considers only the last valid date to compare with the next one in the loop and builds the resulting dictionary.

Here is the relevant snippet within my function. It is incomplete because got tangled in a spaghetti of for-if-else loops and had to give up. This task is above my capacities as a Chat GPT coder and I appreciate any help.

```
# Handle false negatives too close to each other
# Directly pass lists with one element or less
if len(first_date) <= 1:
    results[year, field_id] = {
        'num_cuts': len(first_date),
        'cutting dates': first_date
    }
# Begin analysis if list has two or more elements
elif len(first_date) >= 2:
    # Initialise new list for valid elements
    valid_dates = []
    # First two dates always need to be inspected first to populate valid_dates
    # So that valid_dates can be compared against following elements in first_date for lists of len >= 3
    current_date = pd.to_datetime(first_date[1], dayfirst=True)
    prev_date = pd.to_datetime(first_date[0], dayfirst=True)
    days_difference = (current_date - prev_date).days
    # Branch for valid first pair of dates
    if days_difference > 20:
        # Append both dates if they have a valid distance
        valid_dates.append(prev_date)
        valid_dates.append(current_date)
        # Remove dates from the first_date list for further analysis in lists of len >= 3
        first_date.pop(prev_date)
        first_date.pop(current_date)
        # End the analysis for lists of 2
        if len(first_date) == 2:
            results[year, field_id] = {
                'num_cuts': len(valid_dates),
                'cutting dates': valid_dates
                }
        # Continue the analysis for lists of len >= 3
        # Use the last date of valid_dates, compare with first remaining date in first_date
        else:
            for i in range(1, len(first_date)):

    # Branch for first pair of dates too close to each other 
    else:
        prev_dif_to_forelast = dataframe[dataframe['date'] == prev_date]['dif_to_forelast'].iloc[0]
        current_dif_to_forelast = dataframe[dataframe['date'] == current_date]['dif_to_forelast'].iloc[0]
        # if - else conditions for if one or the other date are the valid ones
        # Analysed dates are removed from first_date in all cases for further analysis in lists of len >= 3
        if current_dif_to_forelast < prev_dif_to_forelast:
            valid_dates.append(current_date)
            first_date.pop(prev_date)
            first_date.pop(current_date)
        else:
            valid_dates.append(prev_date)
            first_date.pop(prev_date)
            first_date.pop(current_date)
        # End the analysis for lists of 2 with valid spacing
        if len(first_date) == 2:
                results[year, field_id] = {
                    'num_cuts': len(valid_dates),
                    'cutting dates': valid_dates
                }
            # Continue the analysis for lists of len >= 3
            # Use the last date of valid_dates, compare with first remaining date in first_date
            else:
```

Edit: Importantly, the decision for which date to keep needs to consider the lowest 'dif_to_forelast' of each date. Considering a dataframe:

```
date           dif_to_forelast
19/05/2018          -0.11
03/06/2018          -0.2
16/06/2018          -0.19
# End of cluster in list 4
18/05/2019          -0.15
23/06/2019          -0.14
01/07/2019          -0.11
06/07/2019          -0.13
# End of cluster in list 5
```

The logic would be:

List 4: 19/05/2018 and 03/06/2018 are less than 20 days apart. 03/06/2018 has the lowest 'dif_to_forelast' value. 03/06/2018 is chosen. 03/06/2018 and 16/06/2018 are less than 20 days apart. 03/06/2018 has the lowest 'dif_to_forelast' value. 03/06/2018 is chosen. Final list 4: [03/06/2018]

List 5: 18/05/2019 and 23/06/2019 are more than 20 days apart. Both are valid. 23/06/2019 and 01/07/2019 are less than 20 days apart. 23/06/2019 has the lowest 'dif_to_forelast' value. 23/06/2019 is chosen. It is also less than 20 days apart from 06/07/2019, but still has the lowest 'dif_to_forelast', so it remains. Final list 5: [18/05/2019, 23/06/2019]

Answer (score 0):

Given the iterative nature of the algorithm, you could use a custom function to compare each date with the previous valid one and add it to the list if the difference is above the threshold:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def remove(lst):
    if not lst:
        return []
    out = lst[:1]
    for date in lst[1:]:
        if (datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y')
           -datetime.strptime(out[-1], '%d/%m/%Y')
           ) >= timedelta(days=20):
            out.append(date)
    return out

df['dif_to_forelast'].apply(remove)
```

Output:

```
                                    dif_to_forelast         dif_to_forelast_2
1                                                []                        []
2                                      [06/07/2017]              [06/07/2017]
3                          [23/05/2017, 24/06/2017]  [23/05/2017, 24/06/2017]
4              [19/05/2018, 03/06/2018, 16/06/2018]  [19/05/2018, 16/06/2018]
5  [18/05/2019, 23/06/2019, 01/07/2019, 06/07/2019]  [18/05/2019, 23/06/2019]
```

If you rather want to modify the lists in place:

```
def remove(lst):
    if len(lst)<2:
        return
    i = 1
    while i < len(lst):
        if (datetime.strptime(lst[i], '%d/%m/%Y')
           -datetime.strptime(lst[i-1], '%d/%m/%Y')
           ) < timedelta(days=20):
                lst.pop(i)
        else:
            i += 1

for lst in df['dif_to_forelast']: remove(lst)
```

Comment: Appreciate the quick reply. What would the function look like if the date selection were to take lowest 'dif_to_forelast' into account? For example, if 'dif_to_forelast' of 03/06/2018 were lower than of 19/05/2018, 03/06/2018 would be the chosen date and would later need to be compared to 16/06/2018 to see which stays. I will edit my question.